# AWS lambda CLI 'update-function-code' does not update lambda_handler file

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

[update-function-code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html) AWS CLI command updates all code files except the handler function file, `lambda_function.py`

Specifically, I made a bash script that

1. Downloads code zip from one lambda (source)
2. Uploads code zip to another lambda (dest)

Everything works, except the main function file `lambda_function.py` does not get updated.

Oddly, when I download the zip from a lambda, make a change, and then upload to the same lambda, it works (all files are updated).

FYI, here is my bash script to download code from one lambda, and upload to another:

```
#!/bin/sh

SRC_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME="$1"
DEST_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME="$2"

export PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8

# get lambda function config
LAMBDA_JSON=$(aws lambda get-function --function-name $SRC_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME)
export LAMBDA_JSON

# parse the code zip file download URL (link expires 10 minutes after creation)
ZIP_FILE_URL=$(python -c 'import json,sys,os;obj=json.loads(os.environ["LAMBDA_JSON"]);print(obj["Code"]["Location"])')

# make temp dir
mkdir -p download

# download the code from src lambda
curl -o "download/$SRC_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME.zip" $ZIP_FILE_URL

# upload the code to dest lambda
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name $DEST_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME --zip-file "fileb://download/$SRC_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME.zip"
```

Comment: I suspect you may be misdiagnosing the issue... `update-function-code` replaces the entire zip file with a new one and returns the `CodeSha256` of the new package.  Partial changes should be impossible.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Agreed, and I just found the issue, see my answer ..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**I was verifying the code changes by navigating to the lambda code editor on the AWS web portal, and it appears this was just a client side issue in the web UI.**

It took about 5 minutes before the `lambda_function.py` was updated in the UI (despite refreshing), whereas the other code files did get updated immediately.

It is very strange that other files got updated, but not `lambda_function.py`. This makes me think it is not just a browser caching issue, but maybe a bug.

Comment: I faced the same issue today. I did not see the updated code in spite of refreshing for about half an hour. Although the aws cli update-function-code reports a success with a new CodeSha256 version. Not sure whether it is a web UI issue or a recent bug introduced!

Comment: Update: I was unable to reproduce the issue! So was not able to identify the root cause.

Comment: In our case, the code never updated, even after waiting hours.  I was running aws lambda update-function-code multiple times and it kept "working" but it was using old code, not the code specified in the zip file.  Only after i manually updated the lambda code in the AWS console did subsequent aws cli updates actually succeed.

Comment: @sjwoodr yeah, I've experienced that issue. frustrating

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may need to `publish` the new code changes according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html

```
--publish | --no-publish (boolean)

Set to true to publish a new version of the function after updating the code. This has the same effect as calling PublishVersion separately.
```